# Calculate how much time a method WILL take to finish? python

Tags: python, performance, time

I know that it is not a specific question, but lets say I have a function:

```
def compare(firstEntry, secondEntry):
  for element in firstEntry:
      for element2 in secondEntry:
            if(element<element2): 
                secondEntry.append(element)
```

this is just an example function but I think you get my problem. Depending on how large those two Entries are the excecution time can differ a lot. So is there anything I could do to calculate the excecution time up front and tell the user that he probalby has to wait for e.g. 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 2 minutes, ...?

I couldn't find a question like this on this platform.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend too much time with this task, here is what I would do.

First compute `T`, which is how much time it takes to run `compare(firstEntry,secondEntry)` if `firstEntry` and `secondEntry` are lists each  containing one element. Let's say `T = 0.1` seconds. Then I would print something like this.

```
T = 0.1
estimated = T * len(firstEntry) * len(secondEntry)
print("This might take %f seconds"%estimated)
```

I am multiplying the lengths of the lists because you have a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement it in the next couple of days and accept your answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't edit one of the parameters directly, it's bad practice. Make a new variable to be returned instead, let's say `finalEntry`.

Assuming both lists are of equal length, this can be written to be faster, in which case you woudln't need to tell the user the execution time in advance.

```
def compare(firstEntry, secondEntry):
    finalEntry = secondEntry
    for i in range(len(firstEntry)):
        if firstEntry[i] < secondEntry[i]:
            finalEntry.append(firstEntry[i])
```

Comment: As I mentioned, my function was just an example. Actually my code looks completly different and is a lot more difficult than this one. I've a filereader which accepts more than one file and goes through every line of each file and applys other functions on those lines. When the user uploads a couple of large files, it could take more than a few minutes. So that's why I wanna roughly calcualte the excecution time.